# Evaluate json error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, eval

Hi Is there any other way I can eval json string.

My example:

```
var json='[{ data: {id:"oxid"},group:"nodes"},{ data: {id:"e40", source:"HK1",target:"oxid"},group:"edges"},{ data: {id:"skeletal muscles"},group:"nodes"},{ data: {id:"e41", source:"HK1",target:"skeletal muscles"},group:"edges"},{ data: {id:"atp"},group:"nodes"},{ data: {id:"e42", source:"HK1",target:"atp"},group:"edges"},{ data: {id:"mitochondria"},group:"nodes"},{ data: {id:"e43", source:"HK1",target:"mitochondria"},group:"edges"},{ data: {id:"mitochondrial"},group:"nodes"},{ data: {id:"e44", source:"HK1",target:"mitochondrial"},group:"edges"},{ data: {id:"metabolism"},group:"nodes"},{ data: {id:"e45", source:"HK1",target:"metabolism"},group:"edges"},{ data: {id:"rat"},group:"nodes"},{ data: {id:"e46", source:"HK1",target:"rat"},group:"edges"},{ data: {id:"binding"},group:"nodes"},{ data: {id:"e47", source:"HK1",target:"binding"},group:"edges"},{ data: {id:"HK1"},group:"nodes"},]';
```

It seems I can not use JSON.parse() or jQery.parseJSON() to evaluate it, there is error there. Thanks.

update: the string is created by my program automatically, I use javascript to concatenate several string variable to get variable json. The json string is not hard coding one. Actually, I can use eval(json), it's working, but I heard it's dangerous to use eval() in my javascript.

Comment: Why not fix the error? Just put your property names in quotes. And lose the trailing comma. (As it stands it is not valid JSON.)

Comment: Why not drop the outer single quotes and just create a JavaScript object?

Comment: Ha, good point @Pointy. (I guess I assumed the OP didn't really have that string hardcoded directly in their JS like that.)

Comment: no, the string is created by my program automatically, I use php to concatenate several string variable to get var json, I will update my quesiton.

Comment: Yes, use string manipulation to make it a valid json string. Or, since it is a valid array/object literal, get rid of the surrounding single quotes and call it a day.

Comment: @LEON that doesn't mean you can't have it appear in *JavaScript* as a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: @LEON, I suggest you use `json_encode` to generate your JSON string. It probably will keep your code better organized and it will generate valid JSON.

Comment: @Pointy, the problem is ' data:' is not signal quoted in my data, every time when I JSON.parse() or jQery.parseJSON() to parse, there is error there!

Comment: @LEON sigh.  You really should post more code, because I think you're just doing things incorrectly.

Comment: it seems no one can answer my problem for now. It's a real question, I admit I should explained more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JavaScript, construct the object in JavaScript I.E. Java Script Object Notation:

```
var myJson = [];

myJson.push({
    data: {id:"oxid"},
    group:"nodes"
});
```

Comment: I am sorry, I use javascript to concat several string, sorry to confuse you!

Comment: Updated answer based on your feedback.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it's still not working, can not read 'd' error.